# jQuery is animated still after callback

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

I have a basic carousel at http://jsfiddle.net/v53Fm/

When you click the start button it will scroll to the next item, however I want it to keep scrolling along continuously.

As you can see I have a callback function in the animation `finish()` which then calls the `scrollNext()` again to achieve this.

However the `carousel.is(':animated')` line is stopping it from repeating.

This should not be true as it's calling `scrollNext()` from the end of animation callback function so any ideas as to why its doing this?

Comment: This should be [fixed in jQuery 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7157)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the :animated selector is not removed until after the 'end' function has completed.

However, this does work:

```
function scrollNext() {
    var carousel = $('ul');
    if (carousel.is(':animated')) return false;
    carousel.animate({ left: '-=180px' }, 400, finish);
}

function finish() {
   setTimeout(scrollNext,1); //runs the function one millisecond after the finish() method is called
}
```

Comment: It would be a much cleaner/better answer if in the finish function we could somehow remove the :animated property our selves. but i could not seem to find that in the research i did before posting. *nods*

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a timing issue. Try:

```
function finish() {
    setTimeout(scrollNext, 100);  // adds a 100ms delay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the return statement and increment the animation lasting time.
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v53Fm/2/).

Comment: That way it seems to be smoother (i think it's what the user wants to achieve), but you are defenetely right.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't get it... Anyway, you shouldn't really downvote for so little things. Otherwise people will loose interest in anwsering. Do bettere questions instead.